# Android WebView not playing youtube video

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview, html5-video

I am using Android 4.0 and WebView to play youtube videos with URL http://m.youtube.com and clicking the suggested videos to play. I am getting following error mesages in LogCat and then video stopped playing and other videos also not playing after getting this error.

I tried adding database path in Websettings, but still problem exists. Is it a bug in android WebView or any extra coding required to get out of this problem.

```
SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db

Cause - unable to open database file

external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
```

Comment: Have you got any solution to this? I am facing the same problem. Please help me out.

Comment: No solution found. I cracked catchvideo.net java applet code to know the logic behind deciphering youtube video signature and using http get to download the video stream.